# Creating an Array of Lists

Tags: java, arrays, list

Is there a way to combine Lists and Arrays in Java? I am storing data for a tile map in 2D arrays instead of 2D lists, because that way I can define a set size for them. Its worked so far because each location has a single tile and can only have a single object occupying it. Now I want to add multiple effects to a single tile, but Java does not allow creation of an Array with generics, so no ArrayList[][]. If each tile was its own object it could just have its own ArrayList of effects, but I really want to avoid that. Also I don't know how many effects each tile may have, so I cannot just define a 3D array.

Any suggestions about how to get around this. I would like more design oriented suggestions, instead of a hack to get around the array/generics issue.

Comment: would this help u? -> List<List<>>

Answer (score 6):

I think a more object-oriented approach would suit you better than complex, nested structures.

Encapsulate what you want into a single object that you can maintain in something simpler.  I see your approach becoming obtuse and hard to follow rather quickly.

You could maintain a single `List` of sparse entries if each one kept its `(i, j)` position in the grid along with its state.

Comment: +1 think about the API for both options. The array/list would be a mess and you'd lose weeks of your life debugging it. A cleaner OO approach would let you get on with the real work. Internally it may use arrays or lists or whatever, but the interface would conceal that complexity

Comment: BTW having something like `HashMap<Pair<int, int>, List<Item>>` instead of a plain list of entries can make per-cell lookup very efficient even if a serious number of cells contain items and scanning a list becomes impractical.

Comment: If the List is sparse it'll be more efficient than your proposal.  And I don't see how yours is significantly different from mine, except that I encapsulate the position in the Item.

Answer (score 1):

The object-oriented way is to make each tile an object, but you say you really want to avoid that. You can use inheritance instead of composition if that's the problem:

```
class Effects extends ArrayList<Effect> { }
```

The alternative is to use an unchecked cast, which you also say you don't want:

```
ArrayList<Effect>[][] board = (ArrayList<Effect>[][]) new ArrayList[...][...];
```

Answer (score 1):

Powerful [Guava Table](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table) ([JavaDoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html)) can be used.